# php in_array search for php array value isn't functioning

Tags: php, arrays

For some strange reason on

```
if(in_array("January", $season)){
```

when I specify "January" in in_array it matches the array value. But when I use `$search_string` which contains the word January it doesn't match. Any reason why this happens? I removed space before and after the word and it still doesn't match.

```
$season = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

print_r($lines);
Array ( [0] => January - March, November
[1] => 2 travelers:  Adult: $9,499 Child: $7,125
[2] => 4 travelers:  Adult: $8,315 Child: $6,235
[3] => 6 travelers:  Adult: $7,975 Child: $5,980
[4] => June - October, December
[5] => 2 travelers:  Adult: $10,799 Child: $8,099
[6] => 4 travelers:  Adult: $9,835 Child: $7,375
[7] => 6 travelers:  Adult: $9,535 Child: $7,150
)

var_dump($lines);
array(8) { [0]=> string(47) "January - March, November
" [1]=> string(48) "2 travelers:  Adult: $9,499 Child: $7,125
" [2]=> string(49) "4 travelers:  Adult: $8,315 Child: $6,235
" [3]=> string(47) "6 travelers:  Adult: $7,975 Child: $5,980
" [4]=> string(46) "June - October, December
" [5]=> string(49) "2 travelers:  Adult: $10,799 Child: $8,099
" [6]=> string(49) "4 travelers:  Adult: $9,835 Child: $7,375
" [7]=> string(47) "6 travelers:  Adult: $9,535 Child: $7,150
"
}

     foreach($lines as $key => $value){
         $search_string = explode("-", $value);
         $search_string = $search_string[0];
         echo "--"; echo $search_string = trim($search_string); echo "--"; //  --January-- 

         if(in_array("January", $season)){
             echo "Match found";
         } else {
             echo "Match not found";
         }
     }
```

Here is what I got so far: 
[image]

[image]

@spirit, here is where the array line is being created

```
     $lines = array();
     foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $seasonal_price) as $line){
         // Only add to array for lines with content
         if(trim($line)!="") $lines[] = $line;
     }
```

**Here is my final code and the final output:**

```
             //Seasonal price
             $seasonal_price = $row['post_content'];

             //Split individual lines into an array
             $lines = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", strip_tags($seasonal_price), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

             //Define seasons
             $season = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

             echo "<br>";
             foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {

                     $search_string = explode("-", $value);
                     $search_string = trim($search_string[0]);

                     if (in_array($search_string, $season)) {
                         echo '<i class="fa fa-money"></i>&nbsp;<span class="head" style="font-weight:bold;">';echo$value;echo'</span>';
                     } else {
                         echo '<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';echo$value;echo'</span>';
                     }
                     echo "<br>";
            }

        ?>
```

The portion of code reflects the result from the image below from Label **January and June**

[image]

The issue was that I wasn't seeing the hidden `<strong>` tag because of my html container on the browser window. I wasn't seeing the  tag, it was being parsed as an html tag.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. It working here just check once http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/72e8c10d38a84bb6ae4888f7b5dd0c3beee28a55

Comment: it's perfectly working on my machine, can you please `var_dump($lines)`?

Comment: @vijaykumar try replacing "January" with $search_string

Comment: @shyammakwana.me it's in the question

Comment: the issue is that I don't want to use the manual entry of the keyword "January" I want to use $search_string ?

Comment: @unixmiah its `print_r`.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me var_dump has been posted.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me look at this line echo "--"; echo $search_string = trim($search_string); echo "--"; // this is the output value: --January--

Comment: (http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5fe441521d4d9bad5730eb1ba103cea7ff3bf7bc) see this

Comment: its working correct -> whats your expecting result?

Comment: i think, when you commenting out your `echo` line, you forgeting to `trim()` your `needle`

Comment: current output is :  --January--Match found--2 travelers: Adult: $9,499 Child: $7,125--Match not found--4 travelers: Adult: $8,315 Child: $6,235--Match not found--6 travelers: Adult: $7,975 Child: $5,980--Match not found--June--Match found--2 travelers: Adult: $10,799 Child: $8,099--Match not found--4 travelers: Adult: $9,835 Child: $7,375--Match not found--6 travelers: Adult: $9,535 Child: $7,150--Match not found

Comment: match found for june and january. thats the result

Comment: in var_dump `January - March, November` this is showing `string(47)`, while it's not 47 characters.

Comment: @unixmiah, maybe if you post here your expected output, we'll find the answer than

Comment: @unixmiah : whats your expected answer. this code works perfect

Comment: @spirit you already posted answer :)

Comment: I'm trying the code, it's still not working. I'm posting the result in my question.

Comment: @unixmiah, btw, from where data is comming to `$lines`? what is the source of it?

Comment: @spirit your question have been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
$lines = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", strip_tags($seasonal_price), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {
    $search_string = explode("-", $value);
    $search_string = trim($search_string[0]);
    //echo "--"; echo $search_string = trim($search_string); echo "--"; //  --January-- 

    if (in_array($search_string, $season)) {
        echo "Match found";
    } else {
        echo "Match not found";
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

outputs:

```
Match found
Match not found
Match not found
Match not found
Match found
Match not found
Match not found
Match not found
```

just like it sould be, according to your input `$lines`.

---

UPDATE: as we found in the chat, data that fills `$seasonal_price` comes from the database and it contained:

```
<strong>January - March, November</strong><br/> 

2 travelers:  Adult: $9,499 Child: $7,125<br/> 

4 travelers:  Adult: $8,315 Child: $6,235<br/> 

6 travelers:  Adult: $7,975 Child: $5,980<br/> 

<strong>June - October, December</strong><br/> 

2 travelers:  Adult: $10,799 Child: $8,099<br/> 

4 travelers:  Adult: $9,835 Child: $7,375<br/> 

6 travelers:  Adult: $9,535 Child: $7,150<br/>
```

so I've added a `strip_tags()` call to my answer

Comment: i've changed this: `$search_string = trim($search_string[0]);`

Comment: commenting a line and then putting a function above one line, does it matter ? trim was already there, you just commented.

Comment: look at my [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534103/php-in-array-search-for-php-array-value-isnt-functioning/64462501#comment-64462501) comment. i'm reflected it in my answer.

Comment: let's wait while @unixmiah will show the expected output and I'll change my answer if it will be necessary.

Comment: @spirit your code works in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ for some reason it's not working on my side. I'm posting the code on my questions.

Comment: @unixmiah, look, as noted by @shyammakwana.me, your input `"January - March, November"` length is **47 bytes**, while mine is **25 bytes**. I'm almost sure that's the problem is in the source of the data

Comment: @unixmiah, updated my answer with simplified version of splitting. can you try?

Comment: I tried it, I'm getting NULL Match not found
Match not found
Match not found
Match not found
Match not found
Match not found
Match not found
Match not found

Comment: @unixmiah, let us continue in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118060/unixmiah-problem)

Comment: @spirit let me know if you've updated your answer. I was going to use str_replace <strong> ?